# NoSuchMethodError: tools.Timer.<init>(J)V

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, init

I have a Timer class and a Test class to test this timer:

```
package tools;

public class Timer extends Thread 
{
    public boolean isRunning = true;
    private long timeout = 0;

    public Timer(long aTimeout)
    {
        timeout = aTimeout;
    }

    // Run the Thread
    public void run()
    {
        int i = 1000;
        while(i <= timeout)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i = i + 1000;
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

And the Test Class:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer(10000);
        myTimer.start();

        while(myTimer.isRunning)
        {
            System.out.println("Running");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Eclipse this works well. When I include it to another project on a Solaris Server, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: tools.Timer.<init>(J)V
```

I googled it but I could not find any answer - why is this not working ?  Cheers, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing timer like this:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
```

And your constructor declaration is:

```
public Timer(long aTimeout)
```

Obvious, isn't it? You must either construct the timer like `new Timer(1234)`, or add a parameterless constructor to it.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you show it shouldn't even compile, as you are calling the `Timer()` default constructor, however `Timer` only has a parametrized constructor: `public Timer(long aTimeout)`.

So either you aren't showing us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), or your definition of "works well" is significantly different from ours ;-)

Comment: Sorry I edited it - there is a value now, I forgot it the first time (old clipboard values).

Comment: I did another test which works now - I hardcoded the timeout value to 10000 and removed the constructor. Was the lack of a default constructor causing this error ?

Comment: or rather the lack of the constructor argument.  Depending on what perspective you have.

Comment: @Tim, if you did have the parameter in the calling code, the cause could be a class version mismatch? If the constructor in the `Timer` class deployed to the server did not match that of the invocation in the client code.

Comment: Hi, the class matched and the constructor was the right one. I still get the problem. I just want to understand it :)